# kill-buffer switches focus to neotree window sometimes

Tags: emacs

And I dont want this behavior. Actually, not everytime is focus switched. For example, buffers like `*Help*` or `*Message*` does not have this behavior, this unwanted feature is active only when closing regular file buffers.

How to disable this feature completelly ?

Comment: You will likely need to provide more of a recipe to reproduce the problem - preferably starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file), or at least a more detailed description. Otherwise, it's likely difficult to help you.

Comment: But neotree is initialised in init file, and this problem is related to neotree, so I must use init script.

Comment: Use the minimal part of your init script to repro the problem. And show that part.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem is simply write my own handler for buffer kill. Hope it will help someone in future.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w")
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (if (string= (substring (buffer-name) 0 2) " *")
                      (progn
                        (message "You can not kill protected BUFFER"))
                    (progn
                      (if (string= (substring (buffer-name) 0 1) "*")
                          (progn
                            (call-interactively 'kill-buffer))
                        (progn
                          (call-interactively 'kill-buffer)
                          (run-at-time "0.5 sec" nil
                                       (lambda ()
                                         (call-interactively 'windmove-right)))))))))
```

You need to have installed `ace-window` package for `windmove-right`, that feature with protected buffers is not relevant to this answer so you can freely remove it.

Comment: You can improve this code in a number of ways: use [`string-prefix-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Comparison.html) instead of `string=` and `substring`; remove `progn` when it wraps just a single expression; call functions directly instead of via `call-interactively`, e.g. `(kill-buffer)`; lift the `kill-buffer` call out of the second `if` since it's executed in both clauses of the `if`; and pass `'windmove-right` directly as the 3rd argument to `run-at-time` instead of wrapping it in a `lambda`.

Comment: I also wonder whether the `run-at-time` delay is really necessary. Also, binding this to `C-w` is questionable since that's normally bound to `kill-region` and is used quite heavily by emacs users, so I advise using a different key binding.

Comment: Thanks you a lot! Im using C-w because Im used to it from Atom. Run-at-time is needed because otherwise, focus is not switchech from some reason.